# reassemble tcp Packets depending on Flags

Tags: c#, tcp

How to reassemble TCP packets depending on tcp flags Value:

I'm expecting a code like this:

```
public void device_onPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
{
var tcpPacket=TcpPacket.GetEncapsulated(PacketDotNet.Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data));
if(tcpPacket.Allflags.toString()== something means that this is the last part of the fragmented packet)
stop reassampling procedure 
else
continuing reassembling procedure 
}
```

the only thing that I want is to know what the value of flags means that this is the last part of the fragemented packet?

Comment: You need to use %f if you want to print floating point numbers. %d is wrong here.

Comment: Whats steps have you taken to debug this so far?  Have you read the reference page for `printf`?  Have you stepped through your code in a debugger?  Have you turned on all compiler warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't simply reassemble TCP packets, because its Flags doesn't have `more bit` or `Don't fragment bit` IP packet is the only one which has flags like that, so you can only  reassemble IP packets using the Flags:

‘Don’t Fragment’ bit. When this bit is set then IP datagram is never fragmented, rather its thrown away if a requirement for fragment arises. The third bit represents the ‘More Fragment’ bit. If this bit is set then it represents a fragmented IP datagram that has more fragments after it. In case of last fragment of an IP datagram this bit is not set signifying that this is the last fragment of a particular IP datagram.

Answer (score 5):

Because you used `%d`, which is for decimal integers, instead of `%f` or `%g` for doubles.

Answer (score 2):

Because `%d` is not the format specifier for a `double`, it's for an `int`. You should use the correct format string, such as `%f`.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [`printf` format specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). `%d` is for integer values. What you want is probably `%f` or `%e` or `%g` or alike. Have a look at this example:

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double x = 3.141;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%e\n", x);
    printf("%f\n", x);
    printf("%g\n", x);
}
```

The output is:

```
$ gcc test.c && /a.out
154573528
3.141000e+00
3.141000
3.141
```

Note that `printf` is inherently type unsafe. In above example you see that the output using the integer format specifier is radically different from the others. That is because no conversion is performed, but the byte pattern is directly interpreted as another type, possibly causing invalid memory accesses thereby.

*Disclaimer:* Note that it's generally less dangerous to use `printf` then to use a chainsaw. But your mileage may vary if you don't care what end to hold in hands and which one to point at the wood you try to cut. Therefore, you should carefully look out for the documentation of the functions you use.

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: It's not type unsafe if you _just follow the rules._ Chainsaws are also dangerous if you don't know how to use them but there's no better way to cut wood quickly if you do :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo It's type unsafe by design. Of course you must follow the rules in order to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The format specified "%d" defines an integer **NOT** a double variable.

Use "%e" or "%g".

Answer (score 1):

Might have already been said, but since you declared the array variable as a double data-type, you cannot all of a sudden print it using %d which is a data type for an integer. Therefore, I would use the %f or %lf to print it. The aforementioned should work better if you're dealing with double data types